# Is there any method to read table rows in doc file by using java?

Tags: java

How should I read tables in doc file by using java. In my doc document there is a large table and I wanna seperate this table row by row. 
Is there any method to read table rows in doc file by using java??

Comment: Do you mean the Microsoft .doc format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) library. POI helps extracting metadata as well as content fron all Microsoft Office documents and Open Office documents.

Comment: I know that library but i cannot sepetare rows of table in doc file. is there any method to read rows of table?